# How to create these URLs

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

GET /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers - Retrieves list of seatnumbers for BusNumber #12
GET /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers/5 - Retrieves seat #5 for BusNumber #12
POST /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers - Creates a new seat in BusNumber #12
PUT /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers/5 - ......................
PATCH /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers/5 - ..............................
DELETE /BusNumber/12/seatnumbers/5 - ............................

How to create the above kind of URL in ASP.Net Web  API 2?

It has to be done through router configuration? How to add new router without affecting the default router configuration? How we can consume these values inside the controller methods?

Thank you,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Web API 2, You could use action route attributes and create something like this

```
[Route("Buses/{busNumber}/seatNumbers")]
public IEnumerable<Bus> GetSeatNumbersByBusNumber(int busNumber) { ... }

[Route("Buses/{busNumber}/seats/{seatNumber}")]
public IEnumerable<Seat> GetSeatsByBusAndSeatNumber(int busNumber, int seatNumber) { ... }
```

You can do similar for Put, Post, etc.

More info regarding routing attributes in Web API 2 is [here.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

To enable routing attributes, you have to set up Web API Config like this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I consider this as answer. For some reason I could not make Attribute Routing working. May be a differant question to ask now.